# have primary key set up but says it is not defined?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

before you link to another post, i am using migrations and all that i can find don't use the way i have to do it.

first this is homework,

second here is a link to a google drive with the "full" project [project fill stuff that was given to help, and a word doc with specifications](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1R6W9pd3E3aKpEe3tuzv2pl5RoYbVrTta?usp=sharing)(but  the last one is not as important)

so on to the problem i am tring to do my homework the package manager says this "The entity type 'Categories' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type call 'HasNoKey()'." almost no matter what i do. i can get it to stop but then the database is not actual made at all.

my teacher is not responing to my emails and the other students in my class that have responed have the same issue, and this is the very beginning of the project and for the last few days i have been stuck here so please help.

i will add edit as questions get asked, i am panicking on getting this done in time so i don't know what is important or not.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, double check you actually set PrimaryKey on your Database table. Then use `[Key]` attribute from `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` namespace.

```
public class Categories
{
    [Key]
    public string CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And also, next time, make sure your ID fields are either numeric or Guid and auto generated by database identity specification.. string Ids are slow for querying db records and to index tables.

Comment: so i tried this and while the error went away the databease does not seem to show up in the sql server query thing, so i don't think it work but because the is no error now ican finsh the rest

Answer (score 1):

Must tell model CategoryId is key. Best to use int as type.

```
[Key]
public int CategoryId { get; set; }
```

Comment: so i tried this and while the error went away the databease does not seem to show up in the sql server query thing, so i don't think it work but because the is no error now i can finsh the rest

Comment: If you changed from string to int, now you must update your table to reflect that change, are you using migrations, if not start a new migration.